# Can I use the Shopify API or no

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

Quite basic question probably but I'm beyond confused. I mostly code in PHP but I'm looking to learn how to create a shopify app. I installed Ruby/Ruby on rails on my server. I then tried to install the shopify-api gem.

Initially I got an error that Ruby was the wrong version. I then had Ruby updated to version 2.1.0.

Now when I try to install the shopify-api gem I get this.

> ERROR:  Error installing shopify_api: There are no versions of
>   activesupport (< 6, >= 5.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems.
>   Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
>
> activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2. The current ruby version
>   is 2.1.0.

So from my understanding I should try update Ruby to 2.2.2. However after talking to my host, my cPanel Cent OS server can only work with up to version 2.1.0.

So with this server am I out of luck trying to use the shopify api?

If so, is it possible to make an app using PHP. I saw some PHP wrappers but no one seems to use them.

Comment: Look up either `rvm` or `rbenv`. You can install any version of Ruby you like, including the latest stable one 2.5.1, and screw your host provider.

Comment: Are you just trying to learn Ruby on Rails or are you thinking you HAVE to use the Shopify ruby gem?  Shopify PHP client: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-php

Comment: What you can also do is host your Shopify application on Heroku as a separate application and send api calls to your current application. If i was you, and if it's possible i would leave your current host.

Comment: Talk to your server admins. Ruby 2.1.0 is an unsupported outdated version. You need - to still get security updates - at least 2.3.x. IMO it doesn't really make sense to spend the time to get something working with such an old version when your priority should be to update your app to an maintained Ruby version.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I'm going to look at Heroku or developing the app in PHP. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The best option in such case would be to use different hosting - Ruby 2.1 was released more than 4 years ago and certain libraries won't support it.

If you cannot change hosting, instead you can try using older version of Rails. Versions starting from 5.0.0 require at least Ruby 2.2, however version 4.2.10 should work with Ruby 2.1. To use older version of Rails, you need to update your Gemfile and put `gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'` there.

Be aware that using such old version of Ruby and Rails means some potential issues - security updates are not release for Ruby 2.1 anymore, some new libraries might not work with Rails 4.2, you'll need to always find a version that supports older Rails. Using another hosting and using new version of Ruby and Rails is strongly recommended.